# Fetch details of a specific customer using react native woocomerce

Tags: react-native

I want to retrieve details of a specific customer using id in react native from WordPress backend. I get the details of the specific customer, but when I tried to show the username to a  it doesn't display anything. The code I used is below.

```
    .....
        componentDidMount() {
 AsyncStorage.getItem('user_id').then((value) => this.setState({ 'userId': value }))
                WooCommerce.get('customers/'+this.state.userId)
                    .then(res => {
                        console.log(res.data);
        
                        this.setState({
                            dataSource: res.data,
                            isLoading: false,
        
                        });
                    })
                    .catch(error => {
                        console.log(error);
                    });
            }
        .....
        <Text style={styles.textinputText}>{this.state.dataSource.username}</Text>
        ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this way

```
const {dataSource} = this.state;
.....
 <Text style={styles.textinputText}>{dataSource.username ? dataSource.username : 'Not data...'}</Text>
...
```